# Как контролировать трафик при наличии спутникового и мобильного

Tags: сеть

У меня мобильный интернет. Хочу подключить дополнительно спутниковый. Во-первых, хотелось бы отслеживать ограничение с каждого интернета. Т.е у меня получается 2 вида подключения, как и с помощью какой программы можно получать и хранить статистику о том сколько за день, месяц ушло и было получено трафика. Во-вторых, спутниковый я хочу подключить как резервный. Отключился мобильный, автоматом включается спутниковый. Включился мобильный, спутниковый выключается.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я отстал от жизни и технологии шагнули вперед, но раньше спутниковый инет был только входящий. Запросы от Вас (т.е. исходящий трафик) шли через другие каналы. Т.к. тарелка только принимает (ну как телевидение).
Спутниковый инет быстрее мобильного, т.к. входящий трафик идет на более высоких скоростях и данные сети не так загружены, как сотовые :) . На какой скорости Вы отдаете запросы - не принципиально (мы их отдавали даже по 2G, а получали в ответ фильмы на "диких" в те времена скоростях).
Куда направлять исходящие пакеты - рулит специальное ПО от спутникового провайдера. Если не ошибаюсь, то оно и считает исходящий трафик
Для подсчета входящего трафика можно погуглить к-нибудь программы.

Comment: http://i-tooway.com.ua/tarif.html - это тот интернет, который я себе присмотрел. Техподдержка сообщила, что входящий и исходящий трафик считается одинаково. Как именно все это дело сказать я не могу. Соответственно получается мне нужно как-то считать входящий мобильный трафик по дням, и целиком спутниковый по месяцам.

Comment: Решение такое:  1) на Вашу сетевуху вешаем "космос". При этом ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО это сетевое подключение переименовать во что-нибудь на английском, напр eth1;  2) подключение мобильн именуем eth0;  это нужно для программного управления интерфейсами. Управлять ими [будем так.](http://itdnevnik.blogspot.ru/2013/01/blog-post_9219.html)  3) по-умолчанию eth1 должен быть выключен (естественно после его отладки)  4) теперь нужно наваять программку, которая мониторит ТОЛЬКО основной канал: тупо пингуем 8.8.8.8 через определенные промежутки времени  Далее. No ping: eth0=down , eth1=up.

Comment: Если появился основной канал, то убиваем eth1, а поднимаем Eth0.  По поводу программ, это к гуглу: "программы учета трафика"

Comment: А что такое космос?

Comment: Я плохо в этом разбираюсь. На данный момент show interface показывает, что у меня ничего нет. У меня на текущий момент подключен моден, соединение я переименовал в англоязыное

Comment: Под "космосом" я имел ввиду спутниковое подключение.  ОС - какая? Рекомендации давались для Win.